# How to change selection text's background color in xterm.js?

Tags: xtermjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7qam.png) The default select text background corlor is white, how to change the background color?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. I also recommend editing your question to be a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? (note that the color supports alpha transparency)

```
this.term = new Terminal({
        theme: {
          selection: '#0000ff55'
        });
```